# Softness of the closing criteria

Tags: discussion

I would like to open the meta discussion on the criteria for closing.
I think we should be a little more open than the rest of the SE community when it comes to questions that are

- **Localized**: academics travel a lot. Something that is localized today may not be localized for us tomorrow. I worked in 7 different countries since I started and I am still not done.
- **"List-like" or "opinionated"**: there are topics that may involve a list of options, and often, academia is not a "this way" kind of answers. Occasionally, there may be things that you have to agglomerate from different sources, in order to get a "better strategy". I am thinking, for example, about best practices for visas, which may favor different inputs from different people having different backgrounds. The "correct" answer may come from someone that is unmarried, and another answer from someone that is married. The first answer may not be useful to a future reader, but the second one will. It's the usual "bad subjective/good subjective" I think.

Opinions?

Answer (score 4):

I think it is a bit early to formulate policies, we see on the main site how it evolves. I belive the questions until now support your theses.

Answer (score 4):

A blanket policy of *"be a little more open than the rest of the SE community"* is a bit difficult to use as guidance. It's better to address specific issues (citing example of the problem) so we can come up with action items and policies.